# CSS style option equivalent to <VendorOption name=”inclusion”>mapOnly</VendorOption> in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I'm trying to hide some legend items in GeoServer. The problem is that I created the styles in CSS and hoped that there is a equivalent option to remove legend item as in the case with SLD styles using the vender option:

`<VendorOption name=”inclusion”>mapOnly</VendorOption>`

I have tried the following in CSS:

```
*{
    inclusion: mapOnly; 
    mark: url(../../images/office.png);
}
```

and

```
*{
    mapOnly: true; 
    mark: url(../../images/office.png);     

}
```

None of which seems to work. Is this a vendor option that still needs to be implemented in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it still needs implementation. Pull requests welcomed ;-)